# Changing a plugin constructor?

Tags: 8, plugins

There is a plugin being used that extends `WidgetBase` in Entity Browser module (which extends `PluginBase` from core).

There is an abstract class that extends WidgetBase, and type hints an argument to a class:

```
  /**
   * EntityFormProxy constructor.
   *
   * @param array $configuration
   *   Plugin configuration.
   * @param string $plugin_id
   *   The plugin ID.
   * @param mixed $plugin_definition
   *   The plugin definition.
   * @param mixed $event_dispatcher
   *   The event dispatcher.
   * @param mixed $entity_type_manager
   *   The entity type manager service.
   * @param mixed $widget_validation_manager
   *   The widget validation manager.
   * @param \Drupal\lightning_media\MediaHelper $helper
   *   The media helper service.
   */
  public function __construct(array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition, $event_dispatcher, $entity_type_manager, $widget_validation_manager, MediaHelper $helper) {
    parent::__construct($configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition, $event_dispatcher, $entity_type_manager, $widget_validation_manager);
    $this->helper = $helper;
  }
```

I have implemented a service provider class to override the definition of `MediaHelper` to point to my own class. This results in a fatal error of "`expected instance of \Drupal\lightning_media\MediaHelper, instance of Drupal\mymodule\MediaHelper passed`". The only cure here was to remove the type hint in the argument list.

Is there a way in Drupal to change this so a type is not specified in the argument list?

Comment: Can't you extend your own class from \Drupal\lightning_media\MediaHelper so that it is an instance of this class?

Comment: Wow. I totally missed that. Way too hot here. That works.

Comment: Although it isn't entirely your fault. If the service is meant to be swappable it should implement an interface. :-)

Comment: Yeah thats what I was going for, went too far down the rabbit hole before realizing that.